# list-style-type: none; not working in Tumblr theme (in Safari)

Tags: html, css

I have the Tumblr Esquire theme.  I've added some css and html to add social media buttons, using some code I got here.  It works really well to line the buttons up in a row except that bullets are showing.  The list-style-type: none; (or list-style) attribute does not get rid of it either in the head or the body.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. In the head I have this:

```
<style>
    .social-media-container{width:600px; margin:auto; height:10px;}
    .social-media-share-list ul div{width:250px;}
    .social-media-share-list li{display:ablock; float: left; width:25%; text-align:     
    center; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

The body is like this:

```
    <div class="social-media-container">
    <ul class="social-media-share-list">
      <li>
        <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data width-                                                                                                       =              ="450" data-show-faces="false></div>        
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
         <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>                                                                       <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)) {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.in sertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://tmv.proto.jp/reblog.php?post_url={Permalink};">
        <img src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_reblog_alpha.png?4"/></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A few items in the fb like code and the twitter button got cut off in this picture, but otherwise it's all there and I haven't changed the standard code from their sites for these buttons.

In the head section I tried list-style-type in the ul div section, in the li section even though it's supposed to go in ul.  I know the css styling that's given the highest priority is inline so I tried it in the body, but might not have the right syntax.  That should override anything else, but so far no luck.

This is what it looks like:
http://the-nomads-prayer-book.tumblr.com

Comment: Can you then show as the link to the site, so we can spot the problem?

Comment: Please try to copy the code again because without it we can't help you.

Comment: You know that you must use that property like this `ul {list-style-type: none;}`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a more specific selector. Something like `ul#navigation li{list-style:none}`
Assumming your markup is something like

```
<ul id="navigation">
   <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```